# I need an advice on how to design a not so common order form

Tags: algorithm, forms, logic

I have an order form with the following fields: ProdId, Price and Qtty. So far so good, this program is working fine.

But now the program needs to do the following; if the product is a liquid and the customer buys >1000 litres, then there must be an option to specify how the customer wants its order (20 bottles of 5L, 50 bottles of 20L, 20 bottles of 25L and the rest in  bottles of 50L)

My question is: how do I save this info?

The quick and easiest would be something like:

| ProdID | Prices | Capacity | Qty |
| -- | --- |  -- |  -- | --- |  -- |
But It looks terrible... the other solution I can think of is to create a related table Orders_Recipients:

| OrderID | ProdID | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |

So in this way it will be like this:
| ProdID | Price | {Size list of bottles to use} | Qty |
| -- | --- |  -- |  -- |
| 01 | $10 | 5 |  20 |
| 01 | $10 | 20 |  20 |
| 01 | $10 | 25 |  20 |

What would it be an adequate approach for this situation?

Comment: I guess I don't see the problem. Why can't you just break it down and show exactly what the customer ordered? That is, x number of 20L bottles, y number of 25L bottles, etc? If you're talking about how it looks in the database, you'll have to give a bit more information. It's unclear what "ProdID | Prices | Capacity | Qty" is, or what your proposed Orders_Recipients table would look like. I'm most surprised that the individual sizes of bottles don't have unique product IDs. That is, a 5L bottle would be product ID #1374, and a 20L bottle might be product ID #9742.

Comment: The bottles are not for sale, just the liquid. The customer may ask the liquid in any or all of the bottle sizes. And you are right, one option could be  "x number of 20L bottles" as you said. the thing is my customer WANTS just one item... and then specify how many bottles for that item.
i.e. 5000L of alcohol divided in x of 20L, y of 25L and so on...
Some customers are hard to convince of simpler ways.
But I will talk to him now. We´ll see. :(